# Large sum of 1/GCD's

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, gcd-and-lcm

The problem is related to cryptography, it involves finding the sum of inverse of $GCD$...

Say I have an integer $N \leq10^7$,
Find sum of all $N/GCD(K,N)...$upto $N$ where $1\leq K\leq N$

Please help

Comment: Do you need an exact value or asymptotics?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki When you see $N\le 10^7$ chances are it's  a programming contest of some sorts.

Comment: its a crytographic problem, so prime no of large ranges are used which are to be programmed...
so @StevenStadnicki I need the methodology or some kind of formulae for that... can you help

Comment: Is this the cryptography question you are talking about? https://www.codechef.com/NOV15/problems/SMPLSUM

Answer (score 4):

We have the following closed form for your sum. It requires knowing the prime factorisation of $n$, so it may not be useful for large $n$:

> If $n=\prod_rp_r^{k_r}$, then
>   $$\sum_{k\leq n}\frac n{\gcd(n,k)}=\prod_r\frac{p_r^{2k_r+1}+1}{p_r+1}.$$

*Proof.* Each summand $\frac nd$ occurs as many times as there are $k\leq n$ s.t. $\gcd(k,n)=d$, that is, $\phi(\frac nd)$ times. So by rearranging we have

$$\sum_{k\leq n}\frac n{\gcd(n,k)}=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac nd\phi(\frac nd)=\sum_{d\mid n}d\phi(d).$$

We can apply some [properties of Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Properties) to write this in terms of the prime factorisation of $n$: for $n=p^k$ a prime power, we have
$$\sum_{d\mid p^k}d\phi(d)=1+\sum_{m=1}^kp^m\cdot p^{m-1}(p-1)=\frac{p^{2k+1}+1}{p+1}.$$

So for general $n=\prod_r p_r^{k_r}$:
$$\sum_{d\mid n}d\phi(d)=\prod_r\frac{p_r^{2k_r+1}+1}{p_r+1}.\qquad\square$$